# removing a pointer from list of pointers c++

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I have a project where there is a main Class with a list of Movies called "movies", and Worker Class which has pointers to some of those movies. problem is, everytime I delete a movie from my list it doesn't get deleted automatically in my Worker list and I have no solution for this one for a few hours.. code is pretty simple..

inside Worker class, wishes to add a movie:

```
class Worker{
std::list<Movie*> moviesOfWorker;

//from Worker.cpp:     
void Worker::addMovieToWorker(Movie* toAdd){
moviesOfWorker.push_back(toAdd);  //a list of Movie*
numOfMovies++;
}

void Worker::removeMovieFromWorker(Movie* toRemove){
moviesOfWorker.remove(toRemove);
numOfMovies--;
}
```

Movies are being added to the list as expected, problem is that once I delete one of those movies, I don't know how to actually delete the pointer pointing at  it from Worker without causing trouble. here is my code from the main class as of how to delete a movie from the list (and expected, all pointers to it will be deleted from the list ass well).
important - the movies get deleted from the main list "movies", and added as expected to "moviesOfWorker", but dont get deleted from Worker class (list of Movie* moviesOfWorker).

in my main class, MovieIndustry class:

```
class MovieIndustry {

list<Movie> movies;   //list of all movies
list<Worker*> workers;

void MovieIndustry::removeMovie(string code) {

list<Movie>::iterator it;
if(getNumOfMovies() > 0)
    {
    for (it=movies.begin(); it!= movies.end(); ++it)
         {
             if( code == (it)->getCode() )
             {
              for (std::list<Worker*>::iterator ito=workers.begin(); ito != 
              workers.end(); ++ito)//look for Worker
                        {

                            toBeRemoved = *ito;
                            toBeRemoved -> removeMovieFromWorker(&(*it));

                            delete toBeRemoved;
                            break;
                        }
                it=movies.erase(it++);
             }
         }
   }
}
```

here is how I add a Worker:

```
void MovieIndustry::addWorkerToMovie(string code, int id) {

Worker* toBeAdded=NULL;
Movie movieToAdd;
if (workers.size()>0 )
{
    for (std::list<Worker*>::iterator it=workers.begin(); it != 
    workers.end(); ++it)    //look for Worker
    {
        if ((*it) ->getId() == id)    //the right Worker
        {
            toBeAdded = *it;
            if(movies.size() > 0)
            {
            for (std::list<Movie>::iterator it2=movies.begin(); it2 !=  
            movies.end(); ++it2) //look for movie
            {
                if( it2->getCode() == code)
                {
                    it2->addWorker(toBeAdded);
                    (*it)->addMovieToWorker(&(*it2));
                }
            }//end if
            }
        }
    }
}//endif
```

}

as I mentioned, adding has no problem, only the removing..
HELP..??

Comment: If you switch to using [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) you would not need to worry about the memory management.

Comment: can't use them in my code..

Comment: What are your issues? Your worker list doesn't own the pointers, so all you have to do is to remove list entry after you remove the movie from the master list. What are you struggling with exactly?

Comment: but how do i do that?? how do i delete a specific pointer from that list, making sure it won't be pointing at garbage? my struggle is that once I delete an instance of movie, its pointer doesnt get deleted

Comment: @NathanOliver, funny, but in this case OP needs no smart pointers! In fact, having smart pointers there would make the code worse.

Comment: Why can you not use smart pointers?

Comment: @aviadm71, if I understand you correctly, you are saying that you do not have a way to go back from the movie to all the workers which have this movie in them?

Comment: @EdHeal, another one. Smart pointers are not only unncessary here, they are harmful.

Comment: @SergeyA yes, thats what im saying.. i cant delete that pointer, it keeps pointing to garbage

Comment: It is not about that pointer. It is about the fact, that you have an object in two places (effectively) - one is a master object, and than you have another list, which references it. Nothing will delete it automatically from that, smart pointers or no smart pointers (contrary to what others are saying). You will have to modify the code in such a case, that a movie itself keeps track of the workers which reference it.Than when you delete a movie from master list, you delete a reference to it from workers.

Comment: I cant, because movie class also have a list of workers in this movie.. and still, i dont understand how to delete a pointer from a list that's all i need to do here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a synchronization issue rather than a memory management issue. If you start by deleting the movie from the movie list, then you will not be able to remove its address from the Workers. Its address will no longer be available. So you need to start by getting the address of the movie.

```
Movie *address = nullptr;
for (movie: movies) {
  if (movie.getCode() == code) address = &movie;
}
```

Once you have the address, you need to go through your list of Worker* and remove it from each worker.

After you have done that, then remove it from your movie list.

Comment: i did that before, now edited it..
now, everytime I delete a movie it does get deleted, but once i try to add a new movie to this worker - all the other movies before it get deleted..

Comment: Why are you calling delete on toBeRemoved? That would delete Worker from memory (assuming it is dynamically allocated).

Comment: Also, why the break after the delete? You want to remove that movie from all the workers.